# How do I save a large file from a web service using Java?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, inputstream

I have to call a rest web service that returns a large amount of data as xml. The data is about 490m in size. Every time I try to call the service I run out of memory. All I want to do is write this data to a file.

Is there a way to read and write the data in small chunks to avoid running out of memory?

Here is what I tried;

```
public class GetWs {

   private static String url ="http://somewebservice";
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    InputStream in;
    OutputStream out;
    try {
          out = new FileOutputStream("testoutfile.txt");
          in = new URL(url).openStream();
          int b;
          do {
               b = in.read();
               if (b != -1) {
            out.write(b);
                 out.flush();
               }
           } while (b != -1);
            in.close();out.close();     
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

   }

}
```

Comment: Does the framework you're using allow you to generate the XML on the fly?

Comment: How do you read the data from the web service? Please show some code.

Comment: I added the code I am working with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try compression and streaming to the file output stream, preferrably using NIO.

IF you have to parse and validate the XML, try a STAX parser.

Comment: It is of value to note that with compression you have to eat the decompression.

Comment: Not if you write it to the file in compressed form.

Comment: I guess I was assuming he would do something with the file after it was downloaded have an upboat.

Answer (score 2):

If you really only want to download the contents of that URL into a File, try [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and it's awesome helper methods:

```
URL url = ...
File file = ...
ByteStreams.copy(
    Resources.newInputStreamSupplier(url),
    Files.newOutputStreamSupplier(file));
```

This saves you from writing yet another copy loop with proper exception handling. There's even no need to close any streams, the [`ByteStreams.copy()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html) does it for you.

If you want to store the data as UTF-16, use something like this:

```
Charset charsetFromServer = ...; // See notes below.

CharStreams.copy(
    Resources.newReaderSupplier(url, charsetFromServer),
    Files.newWriterSupplier(file, Charsets.UTF_16));
```

There's several ways to set `charsetFromServer`:

- If you can trust the server to *always* use the same charset, manually set it by using `Charset.forName(String)` or one of the constants in Guava's `Charsets` class. Be really, really sure that the server will never use any other encoding, though, or this will break.
- A more elaborate way is to determine the character encoding used by the server at runtime by looking at the `Content-Type` header. I suggest you take a look at [how Apache's HttpClient](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2/org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.java#ContentType.getOrDefault%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) does it or just use HttpClient to begin with, making this as easy as `ContentType.getOrDefault(response.getEntity()).getCharset()`.

Comment: Will this handle large files without filling up memory?

Comment: Yes, its memory consumption is independent of the amount of data being copied. As long as there's enough disk space to write the file, there should be no memory problem.

Comment: How can I get this to write a UTF-16 output file?

Comment: I added an outline of how to output the URL contents as UTF-16.

Answer (score 1):

If you really are just using inputstream just use

```
byte[] buff = new byte[5000];
int num = 1;
while(num>1){
   num = inputStream.read(buff);
   outputStream.write(buff,0,num);
}
```

Though you'll need to add some code to detect when you hit the end of a file ~~~(implentation of inputstream dependent)~~~Edit no you won't, and fixed code some

Comment: This code isn't correct, it ignores the number of bytes read by `read()` when writing to `outputStream`. Also, detecting EOF isn't dependent on the concrete `InputStream` being used, `read()` always returns -1 on EOF.

Comment: Sorry misremembered return status. Fixed that silly length error.